# Test for overflow text in basiljs

Tags: text, textbox, overflow, basil.js

I'm new to basiljs and am wondering if it is possible to test whether text is overflowing from a textbox. So I want to write the code to:
-create a text box, 
-drop some text into it,
-tests if the text overflows 
   - if so, create another text box and link to the first.
   - if not, finish.

Is there a way to carry out the test step?

Comment: Yes, there is a way! Give it a try and show us where you get stuck!

Comment: Ok, I have been trying but I don't know how to test if the text box has overflow text? Is there a function for this? The only mention I can find to overflow text in the reference or the examples is the description of b.linkTextFrames(textFrameA, textFrameB) function. But this function does not allow me to test as far as I can see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every textframe has a property overflows:

```
if (myTextFrame.overflows == true){
// link it
}
```